# How to add files without extension in doxygen configuration file(e.g iostream library)?

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard, doxygen-addtogroup

In my configuration file in the INPUT tag I added one directory. Inside that `iostream` is there without any extension. After running the configuration file I'm not getting information related to `iostream`. I want to know how to add the files without extension in doxygen configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small test example (contents is not that relevant for this test), file `stdio`:

```
/// the fie
void fie(void);
```

From the documentation (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extension_mapping):

> EXTENSION_MAPPING
>
> Doxygen selects the parser to use depending on the extension of the files it parses.
> With this tag you can assign which parser to use for a given extension. Doxygen has a built-in mapping, but you can override or extend it using this tag. The format is ext=language, where ext is a file extension, and language is one of the parsers supported by doxygen: IDL, Java, JavaScript, Csharp (C#), C, C++, D, PHP, md (Markdown), Objective-C, Python, Slice, VHDL, Fortran (fixed format Fortran: FortranFixed, free formatted Fortran: FortranFree, unknown formatted Fortran: Fortran. In the later case the parser tries to guess whether the code is fixed or free formatted code, this is the default for Fortran type files).
>
> For instance to make doxygen treat .inc files as Fortran files (default is PHP), and .f files as C (default is Fortran), use: inc=Fortran f=C.
>
> Note: For files without extension you can use `no_extension` as a placeholder.
> Note that for custom extensions you also need to set FILE_PATTERNS otherwise the files are not read by doxygen.

Here we see that the possibility for `no_extension` and with the following setting we get the requested information:

```
EXTRACT_ALL=YES
INPUT = stdio
EXTENSION_MAPPING = no_extension=C++
```

and I do see the `stdio` information.

**Edit**
In case doesn't want to add all files one by one one hast to add `*` to `FILE_PATTERNS`.

Comment: for single file your solution is working but  i want to give the directory path,inside that many files are there without extension then how i need to give INPUT

Comment: As far as I know this is currently not supported as the list of handled file patters doesn't know about the `no_extension`, so at the moment you have to list all the required files without extension in the `INPUT`. Probably best to create an issue in the doxygen issue tracer: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new/choose

Comment: okay, i will create a issue in doxygen issue tracker.Thank you for your response.

Comment: By chance I just found the solution, add to the FILE_PATTERNS the pattern `*`

Comment: @MulsaPrathap Maybe you should upvote / accept the answer